# Docker Error no such container. But it seems to be okay

Tags: docker

First time using Docker for a class proyect.

All my containers have the state 'UP'

And everything seems fine.

But when I try this:

```
docker exec -it laradock_mysql_1 mysql -uroot -proot <../database/scripts/create_database.sql
```

It can not find the container. But as you can see in the picture. It seems to be there.

[image: Docker error and config]

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `_` with `-`:

```
docker exec -it laradock-mysql-1 mysql -uroot -proot <../database/scripts/create_database.sql
```

Comment: @VirginiaVila you may want to accept the answer, since it solved the problem you had.